# Deploying to production a Django app - Azure

Tags: python, django, azure, azure-web-app-service, azure-appservice

I have a Django app in a Github repo. Through a Github action, it is deployed as a Python app in Azure.

In the Azure portal:

1- In "Configuration > Application" settings, I've defined POST_BUILD_COMMAND as

```
python manage.py makemigrations && python manage.py migrate
```

as described in [Configure a Linux Python app for Azure App Service](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/configure-language-python).

2- I have configured a deployment slot and a production slot. It offers a 'Swap' option, to push the live app in the deployment slot to production.

However, I'm under the impression that doing that doesn't run the POST_BUILD_COMMAND command for the production Django app, leaving the database unaltered - which means that the production frontend gets the new fields/updates, but the migrations don't occur.

What's the best way to perform the migrations in production?
Would the correct way be to set "Configurations > General settings > Startup Command" to 'python manage.py makemigrations && python manage.py migrate'? Would that work?

Answer (score 0):

The best way to perform the migration is using the **YAML** configuration.

- When we have the requirement of the libraries which are needed to be installed, while in production, be careful while migrating, because we need to ignore, **venv** folder.
- Create a **dev** environment with live data and make sure to add the environment variables of the database on azure portal
- Once we create the environment variables to the database, then we can get live data to the **dev** environment.
- Create the **Production Environment** repo and instead of creating the connection from GitHub again, take the diversion from **dev** repo.
- Make the parent repo as **dev** repo for **prod** repo. Use the same methodology which you used in the documentation.
- Configure the pipeline based on the environment variables.
- Create an automation procedure to update the production environment on interval basis.

  python manage.py makemigrations && python manage.py migrate

Use the above code block for performing operations into the **dev**. Use the Azure portal terminal to create YAML files and change the parameters.

- This can be performed by **VS Code** also. (**The best method**)

[Document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/tutorial-python-postgresql-app?tabs=flask%2Cwindows%2Cvscode-aztools%2Cterminal-bash%2Cazure-portal-access%2Cvscode-aztools-deploy%2Cdeploy-instructions-azportal%2Cdeploy-instructions--zip-azcli%2Cdeploy-instructions-curl-bash#3---create-the-postgresql-database-in-azure), is the perfect flow reference for the procedure.

GitHub -> Azure **Dev** Repo -> Backup -> Create **Prod** Repo -> Migrate from **Dev to Prod** -> Exclude **gitignore** folder